# fabric: "there was an error resending the invitation"

Tags: google-fabric

Apparently Fabric Beta can sometimes have some internal error where it cannot resend invites. But then five minutes later (just now) when I went back it did work. During the time it fails and gives the flash/toast/popup error in the title, there's nothing else that tells the user what they can do about it. I guess if I have a question it would be, is this something Fabric will fix UX wise?

Comment: Thanks! Can you update your question with a screenshot of the error? I'd love to check it out :)

Comment: Thanks for your note Todd. Unfortunately, hardish to nab a screenshot when it is a spurious thing; and we aren't inviting people all the time. (Presumably somebody could look for whatever code does the 'flash' error message for any errors from trying to do invites if they are bored some day. :-)